# Need help with superfish module on Bartik theme

Tags: navigation

Need your help on this subject.
Pretty like Bartik theme but as you know can’t have sub menu on Main menu on Bartik theme, so I would like to use Superfish module on it.

I have searched internet to find solution but failed, and I don’t think there is same post here, so please allow me to post it here.

What I have done:

1. Have installed superfish module successfully, I am sure.
2. Have created subtheme of Bartik successfully, I am sure too. (name is subtheme3)
3. Added a region calls superfishmenu to subtheme3.info below header region.
4. Copied page.tpl.php to sbuntheme3 folder and change some code to it.
5. Disabled Main menu in Menu Setting, so there is only Superfish menu shows.

My problem:
No.1, Superfishmenu block shows but the width is not like others short and at the center of screen. I would like to make it as same wide as other regions like featured region.

[image]

No.2, the sub menu of superfish menu doesn’t show sub menu but if I flush all the cache and the message shows, which give a lot padding space, then the sub menu shows. When the message is gone, the sub menu can’t show again.
[image]
I am not good at CSS and PHP, and I believe the problem is CSS and the PHP code in page.tpl.php.

Is there anyone can give me the correct codes for them?

Comment: Did you try to place this on content region ?

Comment: Also nice menu better option. If you only want to show sub menu

Comment: Checkout this 
https://d25zd.ply.st/

Comment: Thanks you for your advice. if I put it in Featured region, it works well just like your https://d25zd.ply.st/. I believe the correct codes make it work. Please help me with codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this block in Featured region.Check out this https://d25zd.ply.st/

You don't need any code just place block by admin interface.

Comment: Actually, putting this block in Featured region works well for superfish menu. but there is a problem, system message will show above superfish menu,which is wired.